# What's a good tool (using RegEx) to extract unique occurrences from text file

Tags: regex, full-text-search

Given the following contents of a file:

```
if(Request.IN.NODE_ORG_EWO NEQ "" and not isValid("integer",Request.IN.NODE_ORG_EWO)){
    pageError.found = true;
    ArrayAppend(pageError.errorlist,"EWO must be numeric: #Request.IN.NODE_ORG_EWO#");
};
if(len(trim(Request.IN.ORIG_SET_DTE)) and not isdate(Request.IN.ORIG_SET_DTE)){
    pageError.found = true;
    ArrayAppend(pageError.errorlist,"set date must be a valid date: #Request.IN.ORIG_SET_DTE#");
};
```

...what tool could I use to extract the unique (ColdFusion) variable names "request.in".  The desired result would be

```
Request.IN.ORIG_SET_DTE
Request.IN.NODE_ORG_EWO
```

I can open the file and find all matches with

> Request.IN.\w+

but I want to find the *unique* combinations that exists and extract them.

I'm on Windows. Command line + pipes, or an application that searches by RegEx (NotePad++ for instance) will all be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a UNIX based system you could use

```
$ grep -o 'Request\.[A-Za-z0-9_.]*' file.txt |sort|uniq
Request.IN.NODE_ORG_EWO
Request.IN.ORIG_SET_DTE
```